# Is there an easy way to preserve the directory hierarchy with pelican?

Tags: markdown, pelican

I have an existing site that is structured similar to the following:

```
.
  |-blog
  |-articles
  |  |-foo.html
  |-images
  |-references
```

When I run pelican it takes foo.html and stores it in the root of the output directory. Is there a way to tell pelican to preserve the articles directory so foo.html gets created there? I can't find an answer for this in the official documentation.

*** Update ***

Updating with the pelican configuration file I'm working with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- #
from __future__ import unicode_literals

AUTHOR = u'Donny'
SITENAME = u"Happy Valley"
SITEURL = ''
SHOW_FULL_ARTICLE = True
THEME = 'themes/pelican-clean-blog'
PATH = 'site_content'
TIMEZONE = 'US/Eastern'
DEFAULT_LANG = u'en'

PLUGINS = ['pelican_alias']
STATIC_PATHS = ['presentations']
```

The site_content directory contains the tree listed above. What I would like to do is have pelican take articles/foo.html from the source and present it as /articles/foo.html in the output directory. To keep the directories clean I would like it to create an actual articles directory and place the generated file there.

Comment: You aren't showing your configuration, so it's hard to say what the problem is. For articles, see e.g. http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/settings.html#url-settings

Comment: Have you looked into https://github.com/akhayyat/pelican-page-hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (following [this](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/content.html#attaching-static-files)):

```
content/
├── p001
│   └── myArticle001.md
│   └── img001
│       └── myPic1.png
│       └── myPic2.png
├── p002
│   └── myArticle002.md
│   └── img002
│       └── myPic1.png
│       └── myPic2.png
```

In `pelicanconfig.py` set:

```
PATH = 'content'
STATIC_PATHS = ['p001','p002']
ARTICLE_PATHS = STATIC_PATHS
```

After running Pelican I get:

```
output/
├── p001
│   └── img001
│       └── myPic1.png
│       └── myPic2.png
├── p002
│   └── img002
│       └── myPic1.png
│       └── myPic2.png
├── posts
│   └── myArticle001.md
│   └── myArticle002.md
```